# limits of diamond anvils for high pressure research

Tags: experimental-physics, condensed-matter, material-science

in this [wikipedia article regarding diamond anvils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_anvil), it mentions that the pressure peaks roughly at 300 GPa.

My question is why is this so? is the diamond crystal structure collapsing if higher pressures are applied (like 500-600 Gpa, where metallic hydrogen is expected to form? and if such collapse happens, what sort of phase does the diamond collapses into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [compressive strength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressive_strength) of a perfect diamond cristal is in the range of 220–470 GPa, depending on the direction you compress. (X. Luo et al, *J. Phys. Chem. C* **2010**, *114*, 17851–17853; DOI: [10.1021/jp102037j](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp102037j))

To cite this article’s introduction:

> Usually, diamond is used under nonhydrostatic conditions, such as a diamond indenter in the nanoindentation test and as diamond tips of the diamond anvil cell (DAC) in ultrahigh-pressure research. Therefore, theoretical investigations into the mechanical properties of diamond under nonhydrostatic conditions should be important.
> […]
>
> In experimental work, the compressive strength of diamond can be roughly obtained from the strength of DAC.

And the conclusion:

> From the mechanism under compressive deformation of diamond, **we can estimate that the limit strength of DAC should be about 470 GPa**.